# Facebook JavaScript SDK, Putting Popups in Divs or IFrames

Tags: javascript, facebook

Basically I want to take the login page popup that is standard to the Facebook JavaScript SDK and put them in a div or iframe so I can load it in-page. Facebook provides a method to do this ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)). The problem is that in the built-in method FB.Login(), all the FB.ui calls pass in "popup" instead of "iframe" and I cannot change the code without copying and pasting it all and editing it (not to mention its obfuscated).

Is there a method to intercept pop-up calls? Is there another method to do this that I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this Facebook [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/511/), "A popup dialog is always required for the initial authorization and permission prompt." For additional permissions that you may need later, you may be able to use an iframe, but even that ability has been recently restricted as noted in that same post.  So attempts to intercept the popup call probably won't work, and if you find an exploit, your app runs the risk of being in violation of Facebook's terms.

Comment: You are right, the IFrame thing they support is just a modal window that dims your site in the background. But their FB.ui() method is still terribly buggy. Thanks.